# facebook like button and google plus button slows down my website

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-plus, google-plus-one

In my website I have both a Facebook like button and a Google+ button.

Both buttons slow down my website by creating many HTTP requests with bad latency.

Any idea how to make it faster?

I think that both consume about 1.5s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the buttons asynchronously. The +1 buttons [officially supports](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#async-load) async and there is a [workaround](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=98440) to get the like button working too.